# R.java file isn't being generated if I add the Facebook SDK to my app (that uses Parse)

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform, r.java-file

I am working on an android project and wanted to integrate FB into it.

Using the FB SDK tutorial, I imported the FB SDK into my workspace along with a sample project. The sample project seems to have no problem with the FB library. But when I try to go to stick the library into my app, my app refuses to generate R.java. If I remove it, the R.java gets generated again.

I did a lot of googling and tried the common tricks like cleaning my project, checking for XML errors, etc.

I am now thinking it might be a problem with having both Facebook and Parse. Parse used to have Facebook SDK integrated, but they changed that recently and they now want you to import the Facebook SDK. I tried both not updating and updating Parse, but either way still not generating R.java.

I have set it so my min SDK is level 8 and the max is level 17. I tried raising and lowering the max, but it made no difference.

I have been working on this for the whole day but cannot figure out what is going on. Anyone having similar issues or have insight into the problem, I would very much appreciate feedback.

Edit: I do get this on the console: WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /Users/.../facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0/facebook/bin/jarlist.cache

**Edit 2: I think I figured out the reason:** http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1xajcp/too_many_methods_for_dalvik_help/

Comment: Did you check your problems window, if not, in your eclipse, Window-->Show View--> Problems, this will show what are the problems within your code. Now you can find out where is error occurs.

Comment: Did you try project -> build automatically

Comment: Satish: Yes, didn't find any errors.

Comment: Amsheer: Yup, tried that

Comment: did you check your console window in eclipse while importing your project into eclipse?. use @ as prefix of user name to mention that user. ex:@Sree

Comment: @SathishKumar I got this: WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /Users/Sree/Development/facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0/facebook/bin/jarlist.cache

Comment: @SathishKumar I also got this: WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /Users/Sree/Development/facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0/samples/ProfilePictureSample/bin/jarlist.cache 
when importing the sample app

Comment: sometime it occurs because of target level. Did you get error like `Unable to resolve target`. Yes means, right click your project-->properties-->Android(you can see it at left)--->change target of your project.

Comment: No nothing like that. And I also tried changing the target level